# It is allowed in Islam for women to remove unnecessary hairs from face like beard?

Tags: halal-haram, practical-islam, hair

some women have beard on there faces due to any hormonal problem or reaction of a medicine. so is it allowed in Islam to remove that unnecessary hairs from face or not?

Answer (score 3):

' if women having resembles like men's so she have to remove her hairs only because its disfiguring the women. She can remove her hairs from upper lips and down lips like you said beard a liking hairs she also remove her hair from her cheeks and calves.
This is not the same as plucking (eyebrows hair removing process) which is forbidden.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is allowed for women to remove unnecessary hairs from her face if she resembled to man.Otherwise Islam don not allow to remove such hairs.

Answer (score -1):

It says in Fataawa al-Lajnah al-Daa’imah: There is no sin on a woman if she removes hair on her upper lip, thighs, calves and arms. This is not part of the tanammus (plucking) that is forbidden. (5/194,195)

Taken from [Clear Islamic Doubts](https://www.clearislamicdoubts.com/post/ruling-regarding-removing-body-hair-in-islam-hair-removal-in-islam-for-female-or-male)